# how to Restrict the number of children of parent selected in jstree?

Tags: jstree

how i can Restrict the number of children selected of parent?
please help me

```
function buildTree(data) {
    var dataJson = JSON.parse(data);
    $("#onflycheckboxes").jstree({
        "json_data": {
            data: dataJson,
        },
        checkbox: {
            real_checkboxes: true,
            checked_parent_open: true,
            three_state: false
        },
        "search": {
            "case_insensitive": true,
            "show_only_matches": true
        },
        "plugins": ["themes", "json_data", "ui", "checkbox", "search"]

    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for check nodes you must use `$("#onflycheckboxes").jstree('get_checked')`in jstree

```
 function buildTree(data) {
var dataJson = JSON.parse(data);
$("#onflycheckboxes").jstree({
    "json_data": {
        data: dataJson,
    },
    checkbox: {
        real_checkboxes: true,
        checked_parent_open: true,
        three_state: false
    },
    "search": {
        "case_insensitive": true,
        "show_only_matches": true
    },
    "plugins": ["themes", "json_data", "ui", "checkbox", "search"]

}).bind("before.jstree", function (e, data) {

        if (data.func === "check_node") {
            if ($("#onflycheckboxes").jstree('get_checked').length >= numberOfCompanies) {
                e.preventDefault();

                toastMessage();//your message for show to user can't select any more
                return false;
            }
        }
    });;
```

Comment: thank you s much,you saved me ;)

Comment: you're welcome :)